# Pointer Manipulation: Why does this line of abstraction not work?

Tags: c, pointers

Here is the process I am looking at ... I'm aware about the controversy about 'three star programmers', but I like to understand things so will ask this anyhow ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
  int x = 3;
  int* matrix = malloc(x * sizeof(int));
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
     matrix[i] = i; 
     printf("[%d]: %d\n", i, matrix[i]);
  } 
}
```

then this is a natural next abstraction:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
  int x = 3;
  int y = 3;
  int** matrix = malloc(x * sizeof(int*));
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    matrix[i] = malloc(y * sizeof(int));
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < y; j++){
       matrix[i][j] = i + j;
       printf("[%d][%d]: %d\n", i, j, matrix[i][j]);
    }
  }
}
```

at this point they both work, but then I try:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main(){
  int x = 3;
  int y = 3;
  int z = 3;
  int*** matrix = malloc(x * sizeof(int*));
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    matrix[i] = malloc(y * z * sizeof(int));
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < x; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < y; j++){
         for(int k = 0; k < z; k++){
             matrix[i][j][k] = i + j + k;
             printf("[%d][%d][%d]: %d\n", i, j, k, matrix[i][j][k]);
           }
        }
    }
}
```

the process fails ... any ideas why?

EDIT: Final code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void main (){
    int rows = 3;
    int cols = 3;
    int dimension = 3;
    int *** matrix = malloc(dimension * sizeof(int*));
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++){
        matrix[i] = malloc( cols * sizeof(int*));
        if(matrix[i] == NULL){
            exit(1);
        }
        for(int j = 0; j < rows; j++){
            matrix[i][j] = malloc(rows * sizeof(int));
            if(matrix[i][j] == NULL){
                exit(11);
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++){
            for(int k = 0; k < dimension; k++){
                matrix[i][j][k] = i + j + k;
                printf("[%d][%d][%d]: %d\n", i, j, k, matrix[i][j][k]);
            }
        }
    }
    free(matrix);
}
```

Comment: First snippet is wrong, and it gets worse from there. Do not ignore the compiler warnings, they exist for a reason.

Comment: ok, I have edited it ... but am still having trouble with the last snippet ...

Comment: In the last snippet, `matrix[i]` is supposed to be an `int **`. Then explain this line `matrix[i] = malloc(y * z * sizeof(int));`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're creating a three dimensional array, you'll need mallocs on three layers.

```
int*** matrix = malloc(x * sizeof(int**));
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
  matrix[i] = malloc(y * sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
  for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
    matrix[i][j] = malloc(z * sizeof(int);
```

And then you can access it as `matrix[i][j][k]`.

#### Alternatively...

You could allocate space for `y*z`, but then you access it differently than you attempted.

```
int** matrix = malloc(x * sizeof(int*));
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
  matrix[i] = malloc(y * z * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < z; k++) {
      matrix[i][j * z + k] = i + j + k;
      printf("[%d][%d][%d]: %d\n", i, j, k, matrix[i][j * z + k]);
    }
  }
}
```